# jQuery object html() doesn't work ... but innerHtml does

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object that should be a valid jQuery object. When I look at the variable in FireBug it contains all the jQuery functions I'd expect (clone, remove, removeat, etc.). However, I don't see `html()` as a valid function and when I do this:

```
stringValue = myjQueryObject.html();
```

It does fail, saying html() is not a function. However if I do something like this:

```
stringValue = myjQueryObject[0].innerHTML;
```

It will correctly pass back the object, minus the parent div and text (which I would expect, seeing as how it is just getting the `innerHtml`). What do am I missing here?

As noted below, it was an external library that was generating myjQueryObject that had previously returning a valid jQuery object and was updated ... incorrectly. For posterity's sake, I've updated my unit tests to verify that the external library returns a correct jQuery object, make sure this doesn't return null or undefined:

```
myjQueryObject.jquery
```

Thanks all! Had a bit of a freakout when my code suddenly broke this morning.

Comment: sounds pretty unlikely since jQuerys `.html()` also uses the `.innerHTML` property. You should provide the defination of `myjQueryObject` plus your markup. http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/14/

Comment: I don't think "myjQueryObject" is a jQuery object: jQuery objects do have html() but they don't have innerHtml() method. How are you creating it?

Comment: @Andrey - OP updated the question to use `innerHTML` (almost) correctly. @user - You have `innerHtml` instead of `innerHTML`. Please post actual code.

Comment: You should link us to the real page ( or, obviously if you can't link to it then replicate it ), which would save us time asking you questions since it seems something is off and there may be multiple libraries involved.

Comment: Okay, it was not returning a jQuery object like I thought it was. To be fair, it was an external templating library that had previously been correctly returning jQuery objects but an update someone made has caused it to no longer return a valid jQuery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either something is modifying the jQuery object prototype, or you have a different library loaded.

Take your object, and test for the jQuery version like this:

```
alert( myjQueryObject.jquery ); // should give the jQuery version number
```

---

**EDIT:**

Additionally, you state that there's a `removeAt` method. jQuery doesn't have one of those, unless you mean `removeAttr()`.

Comment: It is hard to pick a best answer when there are multiple best answers. Since I'm using this in my unit tests now, I marked it as best answer. I gave everyone else that told me it was not a jQuery object the points.

Comment: Everyone but me :) Perhaps I didn't come out and say that exactly, but I think I implied that you may have been setting the object incorrectly and yielding a JS object and not a jQ object. Glad you worked it out tho.

Comment: @Dutchie - I'll give you +1 for the effort. :o)

Answer (score 2):

Are you *sure* it's a jquery object? Wrap it in `$()` again and `.html()` should exist.

it's `[0].innerHTML` or `.get(0).innerHTML`, in that `innerHTML` is a property not a method.

You should make sure that jquery exists by doing `alert( jQuery == $)` and you can check for the `.jquery` property.

Comment: OP is saying that that's the part that works, but `.html()` doesn't.

Comment: Yes, but technically `.innerHTML()` wouldn't work, which he just changed. Accurate info is necessary imo.

Comment: I meant innerHTML not innerHTML() it was a typo on my part.

Comment: Correct, innerHtml is DOM element's function, not jQuery, which makes me think OP is getting those two confused

Comment: @Andrey - I don't think so. OP is successfully pulling the DOM element out using `[0]` before employing `innerHTML`. Shows that he knows the difference.

Answer (score 1):

That's odd; try `$(myjQueryObject).html();`. If that works, the object isn't really a jQuery node.

If you still can't figure out why the object lost the `html()` method, post the code which creates it. Then, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

How are you setting myjQueryObject?

```
<div id='myElement'></div>

//Good Javascript, Incorrect jQuery
myjQueryObject = document.getElementById('myElement');
myjQueryObject.innerHTML = '<b>My HTML Here</b>';

//Correct jQuery
myjQueryObject = $('#myElement');
myjQueryObject.html('<b>My HTML Here</b>');

//Compact Version of Correct jQuery
$('#myElement').html('<b>My HTML Here</b>');
```